# Degrees of field extensions

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Find the degrees of $\Bbb{Q(a)/Q, Q(a,b)/Q, Q(a,b,c)/Q}$ where $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3+x-1$ where a is real.

To solve this problem, I noticed that $x^3+x-1$ is irreducible. Then why isn’t the degree of all the field extensions $3$?

$3,9,27$ for the degrees was incorrect.

Comment: I’m not sure why you would expect the degrees to be 3. Can you explain your reasoning? It’ll make it easier for us to help.

Comment: The polynomial is irreducible and the degree of the polynomial is 3

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to notice is that $a$ is not a rational , i.e it is not a member of the base field.

$f(x)=x^{3}+x-1$ ,has only $1$ real root and $2$ complex roots which occur as complex conjugates.

$[\Bbb{Q}(a):\Bbb{Q}]=3$ as $f(x)=x^{3}+x-1$ is irreducible.

Now the question is whether the $f(x)$ itself remains irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ and the answer is simply no because we already have a root.

Now over $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ , $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ has complex roots. i.e $g(x)=(x-b)(x-c)=(x-b)(x-\bar{b})$.

Now it is clear that $g(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ as those roots are complex and $g(x)$ has degree $2$.

So $[\Bbb{Q}(a,b):\Bbb{Q}(a)]=2$.

And hence $[\Bbb{Q}(a,b):\Bbb{Q}]=6$ by tower law.

And since $b,c$ are complex conjugates, $\Bbb{Q}(a,b,c)=\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ . This is because $g(x)$ is an irreducible and separable polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ and it gives a degree $2$ extension . And all degree $2$ extensions over a field of characteristic not $2$ coming from an irreducible polynomial(of degree $2$) contain all roots of the polynomial.

If $g(x)=x^{2}+dx+e$ then $\Bbb{Q}(a,\sqrt{d^{2}-4e})=\Bbb{Q}(a,i\sqrt{4e-d^{2}})=\Bbb{Q}(a,b,\bar{b})$ as $b=\frac{-d+i\sqrt{4e-d^{2}}}{2}$.

Otherwise you can argue that as $a+b+c=0$ , $\Bbb{Q}(a,b,c)=\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ as the comment section indicates.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "since $b, c$ are complex conjugates, $\Bbb Q(a, b, c) = \Bbb Q(a, b)$"? I don't think it's true in general that finite extensions of $\Bbb Q$ inside $\Bbb C$ are closed under complex conjugation - eg consider the three complex embeddings of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)$. I think a nice way to finish it off is to use $a + b + c = 0$. Good, clear answer otherwise!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I have edited.